# Reverse Byte in Java

Tags: java

I have two methods to reverse byte, I thought they both worked, but to my surprise one of them has unexpected output. The code is below:

```
public class ReverseByte {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a = (byte) 128;
        String s1 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(a & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.println(s1);

        int res = reverseByte1(a);
        System.out.println(res);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(res));
    }

    public static int reverseByte1(byte b) {
        int bi = b, res = 0, count = 8;
        for ( ; bi != 0; count--, bi >>>= 1)
            res = (res << 1) | (bi & 1);

        res <<= count;
        return res;
    }

    public static int reverseByte2(byte b) {
         int res = 0;
         for (int bi = b, i = 0; i < 8; i++, bi >>>= 1)
             res = (res << 1) | (bi & 1);

         return res;
    }
}
```

The result of reverseByte1 (which is wrong) is:

```
10000000
-256
11111111111111111111111100000000
```

And result of reverseByte2 (which is right) is:

```
10000000
1
1
```

I can't figure out why, could anyone please tell me why? The first method works well when reverse an integer.

Comment: Should you be declaring your temporary variables as `byte`s instead of `int`s?

Comment: In that way, the loop will never be ended. Cause byte 128 actually is -128, the sign digit is 1 and then it will automatically cast to integer, the digits in the left of sign digit are 1s, and the sign digit is alway 1 after right shift, so the loop will never ended!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the declaration to

```
int bi = b & 0xFF;
```

Otherwise, your `bi` would be equal to `11111111111111111111111110000000`, and the loop would be repeated 32 times until `bi == 0`.

Comment: ``byte`` shouldn't be signed in java: ``(int)(byte)127`` → ``127`` but ``(int)(byte)128`` → ``-128``

Comment: [`byte` is signed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

Comment: and it's a design flaw, imho

Comment: Thank you so much, I forget to think about complement number. Yes, 128 is overflow, which actually is -128, and the first digit(sign digit) is 1, when convert it to integer, all the digits in the left will be 1, that's the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

dejvuth is right, also you can use count variable to stop

```
for ( ; count != 0; count--, bi >>>= 1)
    res = (res << 1) | (bi & 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, the first method will be much faster, especially in long digits bit manipulation. I find the first method at http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious